# How to declare an array for storing and retrieving String in Assembly language 32 bits

Tags: arrays, string, assembly, x86, masm

I wanted to learn the right way to store and retrieve strings from array in Assembly language 32 bit.

I am running this program using Visual Studio 2017.

I expect that the size of the array will be automatically increased when inserting a new string into it and also on removing it.

Comment: Newbie in coding assembly language. Hope yall don't mind. Thanks in advance

Comment: Strong suggestion: Just use the [/Fa](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fa-fa-listing-file?view=vs-2017) compiler switch.  Specifically: 1) Write a small "C" test program that has an array, a string and copies something from one to the other. Keep it small:  No more than 5-10 lines.  2) Start a [Developer Command Prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs).  3) `cl /Fa yourtest.c`.  4) Examine the assemly output.

Comment: When you talk about "inserting" and "removing", do you mean modifying the source and re-assembling your program?  That's what `db "foobar"` does.  But if you mean at runtime, that's not an array at all, that's a dynamic container like C++ `std::string` or `std::vector<char>`.